# Is it possible to draw a line with a semi-transparent color opaquely on top of other pixels in a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I try to prepare a BufferedImage with semi-transparency so that whereever this image is painted on top of the background will partially shine through. For this purpose I use among other things Graphics.drawLine() with a stroke > 1 and colors that have an alpha component < 255, i.e. are semi-transparent. Lines I draw will often overlap or intersect to make sure there will be no gaps. When such intersections occur, the colors of the lines will stack, i.e. the color that was there before and the semi-transparent color I am painting with will result in a new color. Which is logical.

That is not what I want, however. If possible, I would like to paint with my semi-transparent color as if it was completely opaque and the alpha component of the color just a fourth color component. I would like to copy the color I am painting with - including the alpha component - exactly to the image, replacing everything that was there before.

Is there a way to do this?

The following code produces a simple semi-transparent red X, that will let the background partially shine through wherever it is painted on top of. It will have, however, a darker part where both lines intersect. I would like to be able to paint the X without this darker part. Is that possible (while still using Graphics.drawLine())?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a new BufferedImage with alpha channel
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        // set a semi-transparent color and a stroke wider than one pixel
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128 /* alpha; semi-transparent */));
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        // draw a cross; where the lines cross the color will (logically) be darker
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g.drawLine(0, 100, 100, 0);
        // use the image somehow, in this case write it to file
        writeImage(img, "test.png");
    }
    
    private static void writeImage(BufferedImage img, String fileName) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(fileName));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I could, of course, solve this manually by implementing my own line drawing method and manipulate the pixels directly. (Not sure if that would create new problems with clipping which I *also* need.) However, that would increase the effort substantially which I would like to avoid.

A further constraint: I am restricted to Java 7.

Comment: Maybe draw three lines instead of two. Draw one long diagonal line and two short diagonal lines in the opposite direction. That way the lines won't overlap. Just a suggestion :-)

Comment: For this specific example this will work, yes, but not in general. I want to draw lines where I don't know what and where something else was drawn before.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a second image.
- Draw on that second image with opaque colors.
- Copy that second image onto your original image using translucent alpha.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class TranslucentX {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage x = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = x.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        // draw a cross; where the lines cross the color will (logically) be darker
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g.drawLine(0, 100, 100, 0);
        g.dispose();

        // create a new BufferedImage with alpha channel
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        g = img.createGraphics();
        // Draw opaque image using translucency.
        g.setComposite(
            AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
        g.drawImage(x, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        // use the image somehow, in this case write it to file
        writeImage(img, "test.png");
    }
    
    private static void writeImage(BufferedImage img, String fileName) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(fileName));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea to use a second image is intriguing. I also was not aware of the existence of AlphaComposite, thank you for bringing this to my attention. The documentation for that class is a bit inaccessible for me, unfortunately. Do I understand/guess correctly that your usage of that class here is a global operation that affects every pixel in the same way? This demonstrably solves my example. But I want to be able to draw lines with _different_ alpha values.

Comment: Using a second image might be beneficial in a slightly different way, however. I perhaps could draw the same lines on two different images, on one image opaque, exactly according to your suggestion, on a second image the alpha value could be drawn as red, for instance. In a second step, both images could be combined again, and the red of the second image transformed back into an alpha value for the first image. I have to think and test a bit to see if this might work this way. If it does then thanks to your input. Better than implementing my own line drawing method.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you need, but I suspect you could copy from that second image repeatedly, once for each opacity that your lines may have.  Meaning, if you have some lines with 50% alpha and some lines with 30% alpha, draw the 50% lines with opaque colors then copy them as in my example; then clear the secondary image, draw the other lines with opaque colors, and copy the secondary image onto the main image with an AlphaComposite initialized with `0.3f`.  Repeat for as many different opacities as you have.

Comment: I too found all the AlphaComposite rules daunting. I suggest running the Java2D Demo in the demo/jfc/J2Ddemo directory of the JDK. (Not available in JDK 9 or 10; the Java 8 version is [available separately](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/examples/dist/depltoolkit_Java2Demo/Java2Demo.jar).) Once it’s running, select the ‘Composite’ tab, then zoom in on the AlphaComposite rules mini-window either by clicking it (it’s the upper right area inside the tab), or by selecting the ‘demos.Composite.ACrules’ inner tab. Its animation cycles roughly every five seconds.

Comment: I realize now that I should not have narrowed down the problem so much, as it prevents helpful people like yourself to fully understand in which direction I need to go. The broader problem is that I want to paint a thick zig zag line. This zig zag contains a color gradient from one side to another (so, not from start point to end point, but rather from left to right). I tried to solve this by drawing lines next to each other. With stroke > 1 to fill gaps. This algorithm works perfectly as long as no alpha channel is involved.

Comment: This is all in the context of creating tiles for a little game. Now I'm working on creating tiles for hills, which will simply be shadows over the underlying terrain, so that that is still recognizable. For this I need to paint a gradient in the alpha channel. Which means that using the AlphaComposite for each line seems a bit cumbersome to me, although it seems to be a solution that will solve my problem.

Comment: I think I will try to implement it with the second image and the red instead of the alpha, as I mentioned earlier. If it works I will accept this answer, which was not exactly what I needed (partly my own fault), but was instrumental with coming up with this idea. Thank you for your effort and your kind words!